# CreateProcess handling

Tags: c++, windows

I use Windows API `CreateProcess` function. In the msdn manual for it, I have found

> If the function succeeds, be sure to call the CloseHandle function to close the hProcess and hThread handles when you are finished with them. Otherwise, when the child process exits, the system cannot clean up the process structures for the child process because the parent process still has open handles to the child process.

So where I should do this?

The situation is that the process is started and there is no track of his life. Does it force me to make a thread, where the process will be created and then the thread will wait using, for example `WaitForSingleObject`, until the process will be dead, so the handles could be released?

Comment: No - simply close the handles right away if the function returns success and continue on your merry way.

Comment: If you what to keep "track of his life" then you'll need to keep the handle around until you are done tracking.  Do avoid burning up on thread on this, RegisterWaitForSingleObject() can make this cheaper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to wait for the child process to finish, you just have to `CloseHandle` when **you** no longer need the handle.

The reason for this is that you may want to keep a handle to the process even after the process has finished.  You may want to check its return status, for example.  As long as you have a handle to it, Windows can't clean up after it.

But if you don't care anymore what the child does, close the handle and move on.

If you do care, call `WaitForSingleObject` and give it the handle you got from `CreateProcess`.  Or call `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` (again passing it the process handle) with a callback function that will be called when the process ends.

Comment: And if I want to save the process return value to some variable as soon it be finished, what I should do? Is there any event system?

Comment: The event is the handle itself. `WaitForSingleObject` on the process handle will complete when the process exits. If you don't want to burn a thread, you can use `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` to be notified when the handle is signaled.

Comment: Updated to cover the case where you do want to wait.